# Select distinct last messages by pairs in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with messages:

[image]

I need to only one LAST by date and time conversation between two users and here is what i do:

```
select  distinct on (user_from, user_to)
*
from messages
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

I do get one unique conversations lines between two users, but its not the last one.

**How should I select only the last one unique conversation between two users?**

EDITED: expected output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (user_from, user_to)   *
FROM messages
ORDER BY user_from, user_to, date+time DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using [Window Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/tutorial-window.html)

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  (select *, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY date, user_from,user_to ORDER BY time desc ) AS pos
     FROM messages
  ) AS msg

  WHERE pos = 1
```

I strongly advice you to note use PostgreSQL's tokens as column name!

Comment: Doesnt work. It outputs three rows (should be four) and they are not unique

Comment: @ProstoTrader Could please update your question by adding what is exactly the output you except to have?

Comment: @ProstoTrader Do you want the last message between two users for every date ? If so, please see my updated answer.

Comment: updated answer ouputs 6 rows, should be 4
expected output added